# How can I read a tinymce textarea that's edited?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

My input texts work fine when i click the 'Edit HTML Below then Click Display' button, but my tinymce textareas won't work when I *edit* them.  They'll send it's old value to the iframe, but not the new value.  How can I send the new values when I edit the tinymce textareas?  Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms3NG/1/ and code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(buttonid, name, iframeid) {
    document.getElementById(buttonid).addEventListener('click',function() {
//        this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000';
      gJSL_displayInput(name, iframeid)
    },false);
    gJSL_displayInput(name, iframeid);
}

window.onload = function() {
init('thisButton','test','iframetest');
init('thisButtona','testa','iframetesta');
init('thisButtonb','testb','iframetestb');
}

    function gJSL_displayInput(nameInput, idOutput) {

        var loc = "::JSLearning::gJSL_displayInput()";
        try {
            var ifrm = document.getElementById(idOutput);
            var cnt = (ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument);
            var doc;
            doc = cnt.document;
            doc.open();
            var inputs = document.getElementsByName(nameInput);
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                doc.write(inputs[i].value + "<br />");
            }
            doc.close();
        } catch (e) {
            exceptionAlert(loc, e);
        }
    }
</script>

<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>

<div class="scrollbar">
<input id="test1" name="test" value="ajkla;ldkfj">
<input id="test2" name="test" value="bla2">
<input id="test3" name="test" value="bla3">
<input id="test4" name="test" value="bla4">
<input id="test5" name="test" value="bla5">

<br><br>

<textarea class="ckeditor" id="test6" name="test"></textarea>

<br><br>

<input id="test7" name="test" value="bla7">

<br><br>

<textarea id="test8" name="test">HELLO WORLD</textarea>

<br><br>

<textarea id="test9" name="test">HI EVERYBODY</textarea>

<br><br>

<input id="thisButton" type="button" name="Display" value="Edit HTML Below then Click to Display"/>
</div>


<div class="scrollbar"><iframe id="iframetest" src="" style="background: White;"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
content8 = tinyMCE.get('test8').getContent();
doc.write(content8);

content9 = tinyMCE.get('test9').getContent();
doc.write(content9);
```

to get the values from the tinyMCE updated values.

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms3NG/4/) that I've build for you.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I used tinyMCE, it doesn't have autoupdate textarea feature.. 
So, before submit the form, use `.getContent()` to update your textarea..
here is the link [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

So, your code will looks like 
function gJSL_displayInput(nameInput, idOutput) {

```
    var loc = "::JSLearning::gJSL_displayInput()";
    try {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById(idOutput);
        var cnt = (ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument);
        var doc;
        doc = cnt.document;
        doc.open();
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName(nameInput);
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].tagName == 'TEXTAREA')
              doc.write(tinyMCE.get(inputs[i].id).getContent() + "<br />");
            else
              doc.write(inputs[i].value + "<br />");
        }
        doc.close();
    } catch (e) {
        exceptionAlert(loc, e);
    }
}
```